# past simple and past continuous

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

> - 1) Two years ago I **was working** in New York
> - 2) Two years ago I **studied** in England

Both examples are from English grammar books. Could somebody explain to me why the past continuous is used in the first one and the past simple in the second? I cannot understand the difference.(both are probably temporary situations at a specified point in time).

Thank you, Anouk

Answer (score -1):

in those sentences we have 2 action points ..both of them is for past and they finished but one of them is ongoing and whereas the second one has finished in an specific point of time  . for instance when we say i was cooking when he came .the first sentense is ongoing however the second one is interuption. although it is not nessary to come fist or second .only you must know simple past intrupt past continuos.